# SQL query exploit

Tags: php, sql, exploit

I was attempting to solve this PHP exploit, found on https://picoctf.com/problems/php3/ , with source code available at the above question, but couldn't.

I found a solution that claimed that any password whose md5 hash in byte form contained the string '=' or '|' (including the single quotes), would be accepted if paired with the username "admin".

solution originally found here:(in Vietnamese) http://blog.phuongnam.org/2013/07/picoctf.html

For instance, the following log on details are accepted:

admin

1184941

Apparently this is because the byte md5 hash of 1184941 is  8žt¼ø>Pý^0'|'

So why does this solution work?

I get that the True argument of the md5 produces a byte rather than hex hash, and that the @ prefixing

```
mysql_fetch_array
```

Forces sql to ignore the error caused by breaking the query, but beyond that I'm lost.

Comment: Could you edit your question and post the link where you found the solution to get you on tracks ? It may help others to get the full logic of such exploit.

Comment: I don't see any solution, I see sql injection problem try `admin') or ('1` as user name with any password

Comment: m4rtin-sure, but its in Vietnamese

http://blog.phuongnam.org/2013/07/picoctf.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipe symbol in the query is a `bitwise OR`.

Splitting the query up a little bit for reading purposes, it would look like the following:

`.. WHERE (pass = '8žt¼ø>Pý^0' |'')`

The bitwise or is returning 0 (which I confirmed by opening my javascript console and entered `'8žt¼ø>Pý^0' |''`. When you're querying a char/varchar field against an integer, MySQL typecasts the contents of the field to an integer to compare. Any field without a valid integer will equate to `0`. So its' now looking for a password that contains the value `0`, which is everything that isn't a numeric value.

Alternatively; You could also login just using the username: `') OR 'a'='a' --`

Comment: It works for me. You need to make sure there is a space after the -- though. so `') OR 'a'='a' --[space]`